# How do I get the contents of a list as a string?

Tags: python-3.x

This is `st[0:6]`, which is my list (actually it is traces).

I can get some trace by numbers, e.g. `st[3]`, but I want to get some trace by string, for example the data for `ADK.10`.

I know this name (`ADK`), but now I don't know this index number.

---

The 6 Trace(s) in Stream are below:

```
II.AAK.00.BHZ | 2010-02-18T01:19:08.019500Z

II.AAK.10.BHZ | 2010-02-18T01:19:08.019500Z

IU.ADK.00.BHZ | 2010-02-18T01:18:31.019536Z

IU.ADK.10.BHZ | 2010-02-18T01:18:31.019536Z

IU.AFI.00.BHZ | 2010-02-18T01:23:13.023144Z

IU.AFI.10.BHZ | 2010-02-18T01:23:13.010644Z
```

---

I tried this code below, but I'm getting an error:

`tr = st['*.RSSD.00.*']`

I want to get the `RSSD.00` data to tr. What should I do?

Comment: Could you give the expected result?

Comment: / tr = st[***(I don't know what code is correct, but it is RSSD data)]
/ print(tr)
/ -> IU.RSSD.00.BHZ l 2010-02-18T01:23:13.****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by data, but you can extract it with regular expressions. Here an example:

```
import re

tr = "II.AAK.00.BHZ | 2010-02-18T01:19:08.019500Z"
MAGIC_REGEX = "\w{2}\.(?P<name>.*)\.(?P<value>\d+)\.\w{3}\s+\|\s+(?P<date>\S+)"
match = re.fullmatch(MAGIC_REGEX, tr)
print(match.groupdict())
```

Result:

```
{'name': 'AAK', 'value': '00', 'date': '2010-02-18T01:19:08.019500Z'}
```

[groupdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict) Gives a dictionary with each group, but you also have [groups()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups) which gives you a tuple.

```
('AAK', '00', '2010-02-18T01:19:08.019500Z')
```